# Can I use C++ to work on Twitter API?

Tags: c++, twitter

I am very excited to start working on Twitter API. I have looked about this on the web but I am unable to understand why most links talk about using PHP, Javascript or C# only.
Since I know C and C++ only, can I use these languages? 
If not, then why?

Comment: It's just a REST API isn't it? And the answer to "Can I do _X_ with C++?" is always yes.

Comment: As a reminder, you should "accept" answers to your questions when there is an answer that works.

Comment: Until I get a reputation of 15, I can't accept any answer.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That answer depends very much on who asks "Can *I* do X with C++" :-)

Comment: the practical answer to that is because string operations are a pain to handle in C and C++ (even worse, utf-8 string since most HTTP-based API uses utf-8) and there are a lot of string operations when doing a HTTP Request/Response; scripting languages generally have a much nicer syntaxes for dealing with strings and network requests. Admittedly though, once a wrapper libraries are written, nobody had to care about that anymore, but the initial hump to write this wrapper is higher in C and C++ compared to other languages.

Comment: Secondly, dynamic languages can create dynamic classes from an API specification written in WSDL. The same have to be generated at compile time in static language, or you have to deal with the uglier syntax of map as opposed to object access. In short, if you need to access HTTP APIs, life is much easier if you use a high-level language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some C++ APIs for twitter:

- [kQOAuth](http://gitorious.org/kqoauth/kqoauth) by Johan Paul – a Qt based OAuth Library
- [libOAuth](http://liboauth.sourceforge.net/) by Robin Gareus – a collection of POSIX-C functions implementing OAuth
- [QTweetLib](http://github.com/minimoog/QTweetLib) by Toni Jovanoski – a Qt based Twitter API library
- [Twitcurl](https://github.com/swatkat/twitcurl) by Mahesh – a Twitter API library

(from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#cplusplus)

And you can always use the REST API from almost any language, which ist just a bunch of HTTP calls. You can do that for example with libcurl.

Comment: I plan to use Twitcurl.Can you tell me how to get started?

Answer (score 5):

There are Twitter APIs for C++:

- [QTweetLib](http://github.com/minimoog/QTweetLib) by Toni Jovanoski – a Qt based Twitter API library
- [Twitcurl](https://github.com/swatkat/twitcurl) by Mahesh – a Twitter API library

And you can always write your own. See also: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#cplusplus

Answer (score 3):

Let's apply some logic. It can be done in PHP. PHP is written in C. Conclusion: yes it can be done in C. And anything that can be done in C can be done in C++.

Comment: `extern "C" { /* Now you can */ }`

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, there's a project over at Microsoft's DevLabs to provide a library that makes this task more straightforward. It looks pretty interesting, although it's still in development.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca.aspx